# WebSphere MQ 6.0: Can't switch from non-durable to durable

Tags: weblogic, ibm-mq, jms-topic

When I switch from non-durable to durable topic subscriber, I am unable to look up the topic name that I could read before (using JNDI).

It gives an error in the admin console as the topic is being looked up:

```
An error occurred during activation of changes, please see the log for details.
ERROR: Could not activate itft-jmsmodule!ITFT-JMS-1@ItftTopic
The Messaging Kernel ITFT-JMS-1 has not yet been opened
```

I am using Oracle WebLogic Server Administrative Console to set up the WebSphere queue. On the console, I made these changes:

- For the Persistent Stores, On the Configuration tab, Added a file store called `ItftFileStore`
- For the Persistent Stores, On the Configuration tab, Added a directory.
- For the JMS Servers, On the Configuration -> General tab, Changed the Persistent Store to `ItftFileStore`
- For the JMS Servers, On the Configuration -> General tab -> Advanced, Checked the `Store Enabled` field.
- For the ItftTopic, Configuration -> Override tab, Changed `Delivery Mode Override` to `Persistent`.

This is the code which I am running. There are some comments on the pertinent lines.

```
public void start() throws Exception {
    try {

        LOG.info("Starting the FC MQ message consumer / listener ...");

      InitialContext initialContext = getInitialContext();

      topicConnectionFactory  = (TopicConnectionFactory) initialContext.lookup(jmsFactory);
      topicConnection      = topicConnectionFactory.createTopicConnection();
      topicConnection.setClientID(clientId);
      LOG.info("1"+topicConnection.getClientID());
      topicSession       = topicConnection.createTopicSession(false, Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
      LOG.info("2"+topicConnection.getClientID());
      //topicConnection.setExceptionListener(connectionExceptionListener);

      jmsTopic = (Topic) initialContext.lookup(topic);   // Error being thrown here
      LOG.info("3"+topicConnection.getClientID());
      //topicSubscriber = topicSession.createSubscriber(jmsTopic); // Works as a non-durable subscriber
      topicSession.createDurableSubscriber(jmsTopic,subscriberName); 
      LOG.info("4"+topicConnection.getClientID());
      topicSubscriber.setMessageListener(messageListener);

      topicConnection.start();
```

Comment: Your text says "WebLogic MQ but the tag is "websphere-mq", what server are you using?

Comment: Thanks, had WebLogic on the brain. Edited the topic.

Comment: Still confused.  The text now says WebSphere MQ but you are using WebLogic native properties.  There are no configurations for WMQ that enable persistence.  If you mark the message as persistent, WMQ persists it.  The error being thrown would appear to be caused by pointing WMQ classes at WebLogic managed objects.

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental aspect of the problem is that you are connecting WebLogic to a Websphere JMS topic, this has become clear with the last edit of your question but it is not clear whether you are using **WebLogic Messaging Bridge** or not.  The Messaging Bridge is the proper way of configuring a foreign JMS server in WebLogic.  I suggest reading [this FAQ](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs100/jms/interop.html) and this [how-to](http://weblogic-wonders.com/weblogic/2010/11/24/weblogic-foreign-jms-server-configuration-with-mq-series/) that is specific for Websphere.